# Javascript object property accessed via brackets assigned another property's value?

Tags: javascript

I know what the following code DOES, I'm just unable to wrap my head around the WHY.

```
var myObject = new Object();
var foo = new Object();
var bar = new Object();

myObject[foo] = 'foo';
myObject[bar] = 'bar';
console.log(myObject[foo]);  // returns bar
console.log(myObject); // returns [object Object]: "bar"
console.log(myObject[blah]); // returns "blah not defined" error.
```

By this measure, how is myObject[blah] undefined yet myObject[foo] and myObject[bar] *are* defined - and not only defined, but set to the same value?

According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp an object's properties can be accessed via `object.property` **or** `object[property]` however if I add in `myObject.foo = "foobar";` before the console logs, `myObject[foo]` does not get set to "foobar" but `myObject.foo` does.

If I console.log `myObject.Object` or `myObject.object` or `myObject[object]` or `myObject[Object]` - it all comes back as undefined.

Both foo and bar have values of `Object {}`.  So they aren't being set.

Comment: `object.property` is the same as `object['property']`, not `object[property]`. You're seeing "blah not defined" because there's no variable named `blah` to be found. `object['blah']` would avoid that error, though the property itself would be undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with types here.

`foo` is an object, you can't access a property of an object with another object as a key.

Although `foo` will be converted to a string and no error will occur, be aware that what will finally be evaluated is this:

```
myObject[foo] = 'foo';
myObject[bar] = 'bar';
```

Translated to

```
myObject["[object Object]"] = 'foo';
myObject["[object Object]"] = 'bar';
```

> By this measure, how is myObject[blah] undefined yet myObject[foo] and
>   myObject[bar] are defined - and not only defined, but set to the same
>   value?

This message error does not tell you that the key does not exist, as it would not be an error. What it tells you instead is that `blah` is a variable you are trying to use whereas you never defined it before, thus throwing an undefined reference error.

---

Also, unrelated but `{}` syntax is always preferred to `new Object()`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Do not use objects as keys into other objects.

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing the variable `blah` which is not defined.

`foo` and `bar` are defined but it's very strange to use them as keys in another object. JavaScript doesn't support HashMaps by default, instead it will perform a to-string cast, this produces `"[object Object]"`.

So `myObject[foo]` and `myObject[bar]` are both just `myObject["[object Object]"]`

Did you intend `myObject["foo"]` and `myObject["bar"]`"?

The syntax is either:

```
obj["property"];
// or
obj.property;
// or
var prop = "property";
obj[prop];
```

Comment: It was a question on a test.  And even after seeing the answer I wasn't able to figure out what was going on - but converting it to basically myObject["[object Object]"] = "foo" makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

- *By this measure, how is myObject[blah] undefined*

`myObject[blah]` is undefined because your trying to add the object blah which is not existing or **undefined** (thats what the interpreter is complaining when you open the console)

so if you would have said

```
var blah= new Object();
```

`myobject[blah]` would have worked fine.

- *yet myObject[foo] and myObject[bar] are defined - and not only defined, but set to the same value*

The reason being similar to the above one, since you have defined foo and bar by declaring them as objects

```
var foo = new Object();
var bar = new Object();
```

the reason they have the same value is because you assigned them with those values

```
myObject[foo] = 'foo';
myObject[bar] = 'bar';
```

- *According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp (Try to use MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Objects)... however if I add in myObject.foo = "foobar"; before the console logs, myObject[foo] does not get set to "foobar" but myObject.foo does.*

This part has been answered well in the other two answers, but for the sake of completion.
when you say myObject.foo , it creates a new **'property'** ,if not already present, called 'foo' for 'myobject'.

The other way when you say

```
myobject["foo"] //-> NOTE foo is a string. A property is created.
```

However when you have

```
var foo = new object();
myobject[foo] // this is not correct since foo is an object here not a string 
//or a property. inshort adding objects as property not a good idea.
```

- *If I console.log myObject.Object or myObject.object or myObject[object] or myObject[Object] - it all comes back as undefined.*

  myObject.Object // there is no property called 'Object', 'object' in myobject

However, if you say

```
myObject.object = "added object property"; //OR
myObject["object"] = "added object property";
```

then try the above console.log commands it should work, but note that properties are case sensitive